# attr() method trouble in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try to add an attribute like id or class in html tags by using jQuery,
then the old value of the attribute is lost.

Here is an example:

```
<div id="dom">
    <h1 class="class">I am heading 1</h1>
    <h1 class="class">I am heading 2</h1>
    <h1 class="class">I am heading 3</h1>
    <h1 class="class">I am heading 4</h1>
    <h1 class="class">I am heading 5</h1>
    <h1 class="class">I am heading 6</h1>
</div>
```

Now I am trying to add another class by jquery which has a class named 'class'.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.class').attr('class','newClass')
    })
</script>
```

As a result it removes the old class and set the new class. But I want both classes. What's a good way around this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.attr()` is used to get/set the new value. in case of set condition, the previous values associated to the attribute are completely overwritten by new ones.

You should use `.addClass()` to add more class(es):

```
$('.class').addClass('newClass');
```

For adding multiple classes, separate multiple classes with the space in`.addClass()` argument:

```
 $('.class').addClass('newClass newclass2');
```

Answer (score 5):

**Problem:**

When you use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), jQuery will set the `class` attribute value to `newClass`, thus replacing all the previous classes.

> Set one or more attributes for the set of matched elements.

**Solution:**

Use [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to add a new class to the element.

> Adds the specified class(es) to each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('.class').addClass('newClass');
```

As I see, in your case, there is no need to use jQuery for adding a class on page load. You can do this in HTML.

**Demo**

```js
$('.class').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('newClass');
});
```

```css
.class {
  color: red;
}
.newClass {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dom">
  <h1 class="class">I am heading 1</h1>
  <h1 class="class">I am heading 2</h1>
  <h1 class="class">I am heading 3</h1>
  <h1 class="class">I am heading 4</h1>
  <h1 class="class">I am heading 5</h1>
  <h1 class="class">I am heading 6</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use addClass():

```
$('.class').addClass('class-name');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you will use attr() function than it will be replace with current attribute. You will use jquery addClass() method. It will helpfull for you.

```
$('.class').addClass('newClass')
```